# Dynamic Content - based on date

Tags: marketing-cloud, dynamic, email-studio

I'm reading up on dynamic content and it all seems to be based only on subscriber attributes or DE/audience attributes.

Is there a way to have X number of dynamic content blocks that cycle through based on the day?

Use case:
I have 7 videos - 1 for each day.  Instead of creating 7 copies of an email, I just want to have the video section update based on whether it's day 1, day 2 or day 7.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a dynamic content scenario. Rather like a case for Ampscript. Can you describe the scenario a bit more detailed? Is it a fixed date 7 day campaign or more of a continuous seven day email sequence that starts individually for each subscriber?

Comment: I actually figured this out.  I'll post answer.  You're right.  It is an ampscript case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Create content blocks that can be dynamically added by system date.

```
%%[
    SET @Today = Format(Now(), "MM d, yyyy")
    SET @Contentid = LOOKUP('PTWT_Dynamic_Content', 'contentid', 'Date', @Today)
]%%

    Today's Featured Video - %%=Format(Now(), "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%    
        %%=ContentBlockbyKey(@ContentID)=%%
```

This requires that a data extension that contains a date with the associated content block name, ID, or key (depending on what you want to key off of.